# EF user-defined functions migration

Tags: c#, entity-framework, database-migration

I'm trying to add user-defined functions with Entity Framework.

In `DbContext` I've defined them as follows:

```
public IQueryable<GetProjectInspectionsFunctionResult> GetProjectInspections(int clientId, int projectId) => FromExpression(() => GetProjectInspections(clientId, projectId));
public IQueryable<GetProjectItemsFunctionResult> GetProjectItems(int clientId, int projectId) => FromExpression(() => GetProjectItems(clientId, projectId));
public IQueryable<GetProjectLopItemsFunctionResult> GetProjectLopItems(int clientId, int projectId) => FromExpression(() => GetProjectLopItems(clientId, projectId));
public IQueryable<GetProjectAttachmentsFunctionResult> GetProjectAttachments(int clientId, int projectId) => FromExpression(() => GetProjectAttachments(clientId, projectId));

modelBuilder.HasDbFunction(typeof(QAppDbContext).GetMethod(nameof(GetProjectInspections))).HasName("fn_GetProjectInspections");
modelBuilder.HasDbFunction(typeof(QAppDbContext).GetMethod(nameof(GetProjectItems))).HasName("fn_GetProjectItems");
modelBuilder.HasDbFunction(typeof(QAppDbContext).GetMethod(nameof(GetProjectLopItems))).HasName("fn_GetProjectLopItems");
modelBuilder.HasDbFunction(typeof(QAppDbContext).GetMethod(nameof(GetProjectAttachments))).HasName("fn_GetProjectAttachments");
```

I also have a configuration for each function:

```
public class GetProjectInspectionsConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<GetProjectInspectionsFunctionResult>
{
     public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<GetProjectInspectionsFunctionResult> builder)
     {
          builder.HasNoKey();
     }
}
```

I've also created an empty migration and defined each function:

```
migrationBuilder.Sql(
     @"CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_GetProjectInspections]
        (@clientId INT, @projectId INT)
     RETURNS TABLE
     AS
     RETURN
     (
        WITH clients AS(...)
        SELECT...
     )"
)
```

And after I run the migration, an error occurs in `DbContextSnapshot` because EF adds `.ToTable(null)` for each function result type (eg. *GetProjectInspectionsFunctionResult*).

Is there a way to overcome this situation? I think that I need to avoid any type of annotation (table, function, etc.)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to fix the issue by specifying the name explicitly for each function result entity (caused by methods overload):

```
modelBuilder.Entity<GetProjectInspectionsFunctionResult>((x) =>
{
    x.HasNoKey();
    x.ToTable(name: null);
})
```